# Isoleted scope also for transclude?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

I want to add my custom directive within my other directive.
Second directive should use scope from first directive.
Problem is that first directive has isolated scope and apperently it is also isolated for second directive and in my opinion it shouldn't because I'm using transclude.

Here is example. When I comment `scope: {test:"@"}` all wroks as it should.
How to fix it?

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
            .controller("initCtrl", function ($scope) {

            });
    angular.module('myApp')
            .directive('firstDirective', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    scope: {test: "@"}, //everything is OK when I comment that.
                    transclude: true,
                    template: '<div> First Directive {{myVar}} {{test}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
                    controller: "firstDirectiveCtrl",
                    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

                    }
                };
            }])
            .controller("firstDirectiveCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
                $scope.myVar = "Var from first directive";
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.myVar = "Var from first directive has changed";
                }, 1000);
            }])
            .directive('secondDirective', [function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    scope: false,
                    require: "^firstDirective",
                    template: '<div> Second Directive {{myVar}}</div>',
                    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                        //scope.myVar = "Var from second directive";
                    }
                };
            }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="initCtrl" class="container">
    <first-directive test="test">
        <second-directive></second-directive>
        {{myVar}} 
<br><i>no var unless I comment scope: {test:"@"} i first directive.</i>
    </first-directive>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A directive always has its own scope. Transclude only allows you to put some elements inside it in your html page

Comment: So I cen't get any data from required, parent directive that has isolated scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access $parent scope ex. $parent.myVar.
Works only in angular 1.3

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
            .controller("initCtrl", function ($scope) {

            });
    angular.module('myApp')
            .directive('firstDirective', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    scope: {
                        test:"@",
                        //myVar:"="
                    },
                    transclude: true,
                    template: '<div> First Directive {{myVar}} {{test}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
                    controller: "firstDirectiveCtrl",
                    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

                    }
                };
            }])
            .controller("firstDirectiveCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
                $scope.myVar = "Var from first directive";
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.myVar = "Var from first directive has changed";
                }, 1000);
                this.getMyVar = function () {
                    return $scope.myVar;
                };
                //console.log($scope.getMyVar());
            }])
            .directive('secondDirective', [function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    scope: false,
                    require: "^firstDirective",
                    template: '<div> Second Directive {{$parent.myVar}}</div>',
                    link: function (scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {
                        //console.log(scope.$parent);
                        //console.log(ctrl);
//                        console.log(ctrl.myVar);
//                        console.log(ctrl.getMyVar());
                        //scope.myVar = "Var from second directive";
                    }
                };
            }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="initCtrl" class="container">
    <first-directive test="test">
        {{$parent.myVar}}
        <second-directive></second-directive>
    </first-directive>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting. In 1.3 things have changed; it looks like the way that transclusion scope is hooked up to the $scope tree has changed. Transclusion scope is a child of the next parent scope higher up the chain that's available (in this example its the isolated scope), and it participates in protypical inheritance. I assume this is by design - if it is, and not a bug, then I like the change as it makes more logical sense, and its easier to explain.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the first directive uses isolated scope that myVar is not visible inside of the directive's template.  myVar is visible inside of the transcluded contents because it is linked to the transclusion scope, which is a child scope of your parent controller scope. The transclusion scope, and firstDirective's isolated scope are sister scopes - but separate from eachother.

Note: This is only true for 1.2+. In 1.3, it looks like things have changed, and transclusion scope is a child scope of the next scope higher up the chain.

To fix this, you just have to pass myVar to your isolated scope:

```
.directive('firstDirective', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {test: "@", myVar: "="}, //pass myVar into your isolated scope.
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div> First Directive {{myVar}} {{test}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
        controller: "firstDirectiveCtrl",
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

        }
    };
}])
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="initCtrl" class="container">
    <first-directive test="test" my-var="myVar">
        <second-directive></second-directive>
        {{myVar}} 
        ...
    </first-directive>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
            .controller("initCtrl", function ($scope) {

            });
    angular.module('myApp')
            .directive('firstDirective', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    scope: {test: "@", myVar:"="}, //everything is OK when I comment that.
                    transclude: true,
                    template: '<div> First Directive {{myVar}} {{test}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
                    controller: "firstDirectiveCtrl",
                    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

                    }
                };
            }])
            .controller("firstDirectiveCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
                $scope.myVar = "Var from first directive";
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.myVar = "Var from first directive has changed";
                }, 1000);
            }])
            .directive('secondDirective', [function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    scope: false,
                    require: "^firstDirective",
                    template: '<div> Second Directive {{myVar}}</div>',
                    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                        //scope.myVar = "Var from second directive";
                    }
                };
            }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="initCtrl" class="container">
    <first-directive test="test" my-var="myVar">
        <second-directive></second-directive>
        {{myVar}} 
<br><i>no var unless I comment scope: {test:"@"} i first directive.</i>
    </first-directive>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But myVar is defined in firstDirectiveCtrl so it should be already in it's scope.

Comment: No. Isolated scope is not visible or linked to parent scope - otherwise, it would not be isolated.

Comment: This is only test. In real code in first directive I'm loading data from server that should be accesaable in second directive.

Comment: That works - great - now I understand. At beggining I thought that transclude passes also scope.

Comment: The rule of thumb that I use: where is the HTML for the directive located? If it is inside the main HTML and uses transclusion, then it will be linked to a child transclusion scope that inherits from the main controller scope.  If it is inside of a directive's template, then it will be linked to the directive's scope, which can either be isolated, child, or inherited. If the HTML is inside of the directive, but within transcluded contents, then it will be linked to the parent directive's scope (as a child transclusion scope).

Comment: I've noticed that I can use $scope.$parent from within second directive which has all parent scope

Comment: Yes because transclusion scope is a child scope of the main controller scope. Even though you specify scope:false (meaning it inherits scope), using transclusion creates a child scope.